# Doctrine2 Flush a Single Removed Entity

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Trying to remove an entity, without persisting other changes. Note that (while in this specific situation it's not really needed) the method should not effect the outcome of a `flush()` called after the action.

```
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush($entity);
```

That throws an `'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Entity has to be managed for single computation`.

I can just use DQL to do the remove; just was wondering if there's a way to do it through the entity manager.

Comment: Looks like a bug, An entity that is in the removed state is managed.

Comment: @meze Yeah, thought it might be. Also thought that flushing a single object is probably something with limitations.

Comment: @meze, I don't think so that the code above has a bug. The only incorrect thing that I see is the fact that `flush()` does not receive any argument.

Comment: @manix Support for passing an entity to `flush()` has [been around for a while](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/166).

Comment: Well well... I should update my API xD

Answer (score 3):

I forgot about [transactions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html), which I'll have to test:

```
// $em instanceof EntityManager
$em->transactional(function($em) {
    $em->remove($entity);
});
```

Just not certain I can use a transaction if entities changed before and after the transaction are *not* in an explicit transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

1. Detach the entity from current EM:

   ```
   $em->detach($entity);
   ```
2. Create a new instance of EM and work with it to remove:

   ```
   $em2->remove($entity);
   $em2->flush();
   ```

Or, you can use the method `clear()` that is in charge of detach all entities from the EM, like this:

```
$em->clear();
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: It will flush all changed entities.

Comment: @manix Interesting workaround - simpler is just doing a delete with DQL, but had not thought of creating a second instance of the entity manager.

Comment: Can someone explain why is this whole workaround needed in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is :

```
$entity = $em->manage($entity);
// $entity now refers to the fully managed copy returned by the merge operation.
// The EntityManager $em now manages the persistence of $entity as usual
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. Please, read the question again: "ONLY remove single entity".